# Do I have to use queryProfiles every time to get the profile id?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am playing with Google Analytics API and found that when I get the web property list, I have a `defaultProfileId` very useful. It can just help me pass the `queryProfiles` call, to save one request and make the whole app works faster.

But I noticed that some web properties just don't have the `defaultProfileId` thing.

Just for the information, most of the situations happens to a tracking ID like `UA-XXXX-1`.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for finding defaultProfileId I hadn't noticed that before

Answer (score 2):

You are correct `webProperty` does not always return a `defaultProfileId`.  I was also unable to find any information on the [Web Properties](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties) page as to how the API decides what a Default Profile Id is.   I submitted a bug report for it, with the Analytics dev team you can find it at: [defaultProfileId - not always sent with a WebProperty](http://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=405&thanks=405&ts=1393855658). Lets hope they come with a response you are correct this is a very useful feature.

Yes you are probably going to have to query the profiles every time to get the correct profile you are after.

---

I just found this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/~all/webproperties/~all/profiles?oauth_token={Token}
```

There should be away of working that to make one request for accounts, one to get all the Web Properties , then one to get all the Profiles.

Comment: In some cases a property does not have a default view/profile set which is why you won't see defaultProfileId in the API response.

Comment: Webpropertyid returns defaultprofileid only when you give live URl which is working to account.